# Save CSV File without storage permission by using file provider

Tags: android, kotlin

Save CSV File without storage permission by using file provider.

I need Kotlin code in which CSV file save in external storage without storage permission

I need Kotlin code in which CSV file save in external storage without storage permission

Comment: FileProvider is not for saving files by your app. FileProvider is for serving existing files to other apps. Or creating files by other apps.

Comment: You can save any file to getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir() (-Jave notation- get the equivalent for kotlin)  without any permission.

Comment: So, Save CSV File without storage permission without file provider.

Comment: File save only in user select folder.

Comment: It is time you completely rewrite your post as you come up with all kind of new things.